# Pass a variable function to component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I try to upload a video in react-js and preview but i am failed, how to pass the **fi** variable to the **url** section my code like

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

function Video(props) {

    const [file,setFile] = useState( null );

    const onInputValue = (e) => {
      var fi =   URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
      console.log(fi);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="#" id="#">
                <input type="file" onChange={onInputValue}/>
                <button>Upload</button>
            </form>

            <ReactPlayer
            controls
            url={fi} 
            id="videoz" />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Video;
```

i do this way but show error in **fi** variable error

```
src\components\Video.js
  Line 22:18:  'fi' is not defined  no-undef
```

how to solve this issue, i am new in react!

Comment: try using fi as state using `useState()` and update it in `onInputValue` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `var` fi, is scoped to the function. It is not visible outside `onInputValue`. Hence the error.

The variable you want to use, should cause a rerender when it is changed. State is the logical solution. You can use a state variable with useState which will be updated.

```
function Video(props) {

    const [file,setFile] = useState( null );
    const [fi,setFi] = useState('');

    const onInputValue = (e) => {
      var newFi =   URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
console.log(newFi); 
setFi(newFi);    
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="#" id="#">
                <input type="file" onChange={onInputValue}/>
                <button>Upload</button>
            </form>

            <ReactPlayer
            controls
            url={fi} 
            id="videoz" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you save your fi inside a state, so then you can pass it to your `ReactPlayer`, which then would need a validation to see if it's not null.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';

function Video(props) {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [fi, setFi] = useState(null);

  const onInputValue = (e) => {
    setFi(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    console.log(fi);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form method="post" action="#" id="#">
        <input type="file" onChange={onInputValue} />
        <button>Upload</button>
      </form>

      <ReactPlayer controls url={fi} id="videoz" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Video;
```